# Prevent ifelse() in R from turning factor into numeric

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, data1:

```
ID <- c('ID1','ID2','ID3','ID4','ID5','ID6','ID7')
cr <- c(1,1,"d","d","e","e","e")
hr <- c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)
br <- c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)
data1 <- data.frame(ID,cr,hr,br)

   ID cr    hr    br
1 ID1  1  TRUE FALSE
2 ID2  1  TRUE  TRUE
3 ID3  d FALSE  TRUE
4 ID4  d  TRUE  TRUE
5 ID5  e FALSE FALSE
6 ID6  e FALSE FALSE
7 ID7  e FALSE FALSE
```

I want to apply the following ifelse statement:

```
first<-2;last<-length(data1)
for (to_na in first : last){
    if(names(data1)[to_na]!="att"){
    data1[,to_na]<-
     ifelse(data1$hr|data1$br ,NA,data1[,to_na])
}
```

But the result is this:

```
   ID cr    hr    br
1 ID1 NA    NA    NA
2 ID2 NA    NA    NA
3 ID3 NA    NA    NA
4 ID4 NA    NA    NA
5 ID5  3 FALSE FALSE
6 ID6  3 FALSE FALSE
7 ID7  3 FALSE FALSE
```

You'll notice that "e" in data1$cr has been converted to 3, because the first row in data1$cr starts with a number (it is converting that column to numeric class, rather than keeping it as a factor class).  What is the best way for avoiding this?

Comment: You can convert it to `character` class

Comment: The row in which this happen changes depending on the input data - would your solution be to convert the entire dataframe to character class?

Comment: "the following ifelse statement" -- it helps to also say in words what you're trying to do. R already has functions for fiddling with NAs and perhaps one of them fits here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a better way of doing this but keeping your code you can do this:

```
index <- data1$hr|data1$br
first<-2;last<-length(data1)

for (i in first : last){
  if(names(data1)[i]!="att"){
    data1[index,i] <- NA  }}
```